# Could not compile build.gradle

Tags: gradle, spock

I don't set up gradle enough to be good at it, so looking for some assist here.

I have this build.gradle setting up for spock tests

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

group 'yoga.radicallyrooted'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.5'

    testImplementation {
        'org.spockframework:spock-core',
        'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.11',
        'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    }

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I try to load it, I get:

```
Build file '/home/thomas/workspace/radicallyrootedpayroll/build.gradle' line: 13

Could not compile build file '/home/thomas/workspace/radicallyrootedpayroll/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/home/thomas/workspace/radicallyrootedpayroll/build.gradle': 13: Unexpected input: '{' @ line 13, column 14.
     dependencies {
                  ^
```

No idea where to go from here.

Comment: `testImplementation {...}` should be `testImplementation (...)`

Comment: It should rather be 3 lines, instead of inventing new syntax.

Comment: Answer is explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49112492/14226243

Comment: See https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example for an example project